# PIM Contacts in Rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I have RhoMobile application where the users can add contacts to their mobile devices. It works great in all devices including Android, iOS 5 and below  but it does not work on iOS 6 . Is anyone else having this problem? I believe that Apple changed the PIM implementation on iOS 6 and that may be what is causing the problem.

My code:

```
def add_contact
    Rho::RhoContact.create! ({"first_name" => "John", "last_name" => "Doe"}) 
end
```

I've enabled pim capabilities in the build.yml

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From iOS 6 up, an app can’t access the user’s contacts without their permission. When we execute -> Rho::RhoContact.create! , the RhoMobile app tries to access the address book the permission to which the user has not yet given. Also, the app won't ask for the permission by itself. You ned to forcefully trigger a request for permission from within the app.

you can do this as follows:-

Go to Rhodes-3.4.3(my rhodes version is 3.4.2) -> platform -> iPhone -> Classes -> Phonebook -> Phonebook.m

open it in a text editor or xCode.

At the top of the page, define the following:-

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Once that is done, find the function ->

```
void* openPhonebook()
```

find the line ->

```
memset(phonebook, 0, sizeof(LocalPhonebook));
```

below this line replace whatever code is present with ->

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {
    CFErrorRef myError = NULL;
    phonebook->_ab = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &myError);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(phonebook->_ab, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        if (granted) {
            phonebook->_people = NULL;
            phonebook->_len = 0;
        } else {
            // Handle the error
        }
    });
}
else{
    // for iOS < 6
    phonebook->_ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
    if (phonebook->_ab) {
        phonebook->_people = NULL;
        phonebook->_len = 0;
    }
}

return phonebook;
```

in the above code, phonebook->_ab is my ABAddressBook reference

Now you should be good to go... hope this is useful...